# Lookup and Replace with two files in awk

Tags: input, awk, gawk

I am trying to correct one file with another with a single line of AWK code.  I am trying to take $1 from FILE2, look it up in FILE1, get the corresponding $3 and $4.  After I set them as variables I want the program to stop evaluating FILE1, change $10 and $11 from FILE2 to the values of the variables, and print this out.

I am having trouble getting the awk to switch from FILE1 to FILE2 after I have extracted the variables.  I've tried nextfile, but this resets the program and it tires to extract variables from FILE2, I set NR to the last Record, but it did not switch.

I am also doing a loop to get each line out of FILE1, but if that can be part of the script I am sure it would speed things up not having to reopen awk over and over again.

here is the parts I have figured out.

```
for file in `cut -f 1 FILE2`; do
awk -v a=$file '$1=a{s=$2;q=$4; ---GO TO FILE1---}{if ($1==a) {$10=s; $11=q; print 0;exit}' FILE1 FILE2 >> FILEOUT
done
```

a quick example set NOTE:  Despite how I have this written, the two files are not in the same order and on the order of 8GB in size, so a little unwieldy to sort.

FILE1

```
A 12345 + AJD$JD
B 12504 + DKFJ#%
C 52042 + DSJTJE
```

FILE2

```
A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 345 D$J 
B 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 250 KFJ
C 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 204 SJT
```

OUTFILE

```
A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12345 AJD$JD 
B 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12504 DKFJ#%
C 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 52042 DSJTJE
```

This is the code I got to work based on Kent's answer below.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2" "$4;next}$1 in a{$9=$9" "a[$1]}{$10="";$11=""}2' f1 f2
```

Comment: providing input/output examples will help you get answer sooner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2" "$4;next}$1 in a{NF-=2;$0=$0" "a[$1]}7' f1 f2
A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12345 AJD$JD
B 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12504 DKFJ#%
C 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 52042 DSJTJE
```

Comment: I checked this on my files, I am just getting the unchanged f2 as output.  I think one problem is that F1 has all the lines in F2, but not vise versa.  I guess I could try it with the full set and see what happens.

Comment: @user2348290 that shouldn't be problem. can you test with the small example in your question, if my one-liner works for it?

Comment: alright I figured out what was going on ($1 in f1 had a @ in front of the $1).  The only problem I am having is there are optional fields after $11 which are sometimes there and sometimes not (Sorry I didn't include this in my example). How can I get this script to strickly replace $10 and $11 with the array input?

Comment: okay so I edited the code to do what i wanted it to do.  I've put it in the original post.  but I don't understand 2 parts of it.  Part 1: I don't understand why the output prints without a print command.  Part 2 (Which I think is part of my first question)  what does the number at the end of the statement do "7".  I changed it to other numbers with no clear affect.  Just curious

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop over the files repeatedly - just read one file and store the relevant fields in arrays keyed on `$1`, then go through the other file and use those arrays to look up the values you want to insert.

```
awk '(FILENAME=="FILE1"){y[$1]=$2;z[$1]=$4}; (FILENAME=="FILE2" && $1 in y){$10=y[$1];$11=z[$1];print $0}' FILE1 FILE2
```

That said, it sounds like you might have a use for the `join` command here rather than messing about with awk (the above script assumes all your `$1`/`$2`/`$4` values will fit in memory).

Comment: quick qustion,  shoudl the second part start "(FILENAME=="FILE2" && x[$1]==$1)"   ?

Comment: No. `x` is intended to be an array that lets us easily check which values of `$1` exist in FILE1.  The fact that a key exists in that array is the important thing - the value stored at that key is irrelevant (I just used the constant `1`).

Comment: Actually, my code was a bit brain-dead - reading the other answer reminded me of the `in` operator, which I probably should have used instead.  I've edited my answer to use this and get rid of `x` - hopefully the intent of that check is now clear.

Comment: I'm still working through understanding this (I am having a hard time grasping arrays).  However the output I get has nothing for $10 and $11.

Comment: description above was not accurate.  I don't get any output if I have it setup FILENAME==FILE1  and FILENAME==FILE2.  When I make them the same, I get the file unaltered (if I correct the columns put into the array.